# using mat-sidenav-container - on mobile devices address bar is not hidden on scrolling

Tags: angular, mobile, angular-material2

When using mat-sidenav-container from angular material2 project (https://github.com/angular/material2) on mobile devices the address bar is not hidden when scrolling...

The reason is maybe that the scrolling content is placed inside mat-sidenav-content.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?